# "context.setDocumentMode" fails in Xpage Extension Library toolbar

Tags: xpages

I am simply try to put the document in the edit mode using the toolbar from the Extension Library.  Below is the source for the toolbar.  When this is clicked the page refreshes but the mode does not change.  I have also added a regular button with the same code in the on-click event and it works there.

```
<xe:toolbar id="toolbar2" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold">
<xe:this.treeNodes><xe:basicContainerNode label="Article Actions">
<xe:this.children>
<xe:basicLeafNode label="Edit Article" submitValue="Edit" rendered="#
{javascript:!document1.isEditable();}">
</xe:basicLeafNode></xe:this.children></xe:basicContainerNode>
</xe:this.treeNodes><xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
refreshMode="complete"><xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var aChoice =
 context.getSubmittedValue();
switch(aChoice){case "edit": context.setDocumentMode("document1","edit");
}}]]></xe:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xe:toolbar>
```

Comment: Did you paste this in the source, or add from the pallet?  What I am getting at is, does your xp:View tag include the namespace for the extenstion library?  xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"

Comment: Sorry "palette" :) To fix just add in any control from the palette and remove, and it will automatically add namespace.

Comment: @SteveZavocki I think in that case it wouldn't compile at all...

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth Yes, correct :) It will save, but you will get an error.

Comment: submitValue="Edit", switch case is "edit". spot the difference...

Comment: "Edit" vs. "edit"  wow.  THANKS.  You don't know how long I have stared at the forest and not seen the tree.